# Javascript - detecting scroll attempt when window.pageYOffset is already 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is on the page load pushed down out of the view and then exposed later and pushed up to the `top-bar` and takes over the rest of the screen on click function by changing the top style in my function like this:

```
$('#drawer').animate({
      top: 92
    }, 500);
```

I would like to when that div is visible, to detect if the user is scrolling  up and when it attempts to scroll up that the div slides down by the amount of pixels the user is scrolling up. I am not sure how to exactly do that.

In my script `scroll-event.js` I have tried to setup a function where I would on document ready first declare global variable `drawerIsUp = false;`, check if it is false or true and then execute the scrolling part. But, since when the `drawer` is up the `window.pageYOffset` is `0`, how can I keep adding pixels to the div `top` style if the user tries to scroll but the `window.pageYOffset` is `0` already?

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
    drawerDiv = this.getElementById("drawer");
    topBar = this.getElementById("top-bar");
    drawerIsUp = false;


    scrollDrawer = function () {
      if (drawerIsUp) {
  console.log('entered');
        function winScroll() {
           drawerDiv.style.top = window.pageYOffset + "px";
        }
          winScroll();
          $(window).bind({scroll: winScroll});
      }
    }

});
```

And this is the html:

```
         <div id="app">
            <div id="bg">
            </div>

              @section('topBar')
                @include('customer.layouts.partials.top-bar')
              @show
            <div id="main-section">
              @section('header')
                @include('customer.layouts.partials.header')
              @show

              @section('carousel')
                @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['function' => 'drawer', 'carouselPadding' => ''])
              @show
            </div>

            <div id="drawer">
              <div id="magazine-detail">
              </div>
              <div id="magazine-detail-carousel">
                @section('magazine-detail-carousel')
                  @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['function' => 'magazineDetail', 'carouselPadding' => 'carouselPadding'])
                @show
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
```

So, the drawer gets over the `main-section` on click, and then when it is over I should move it down if the user scrolls up from it.

The css for the drawer and top bar:

```
#main-section {
  height: calc(100vh - 92px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top:77px;
}

#drawer {
  z-index: 5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100vh;
  height: calc(100vh - 92px);
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $white;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `drawer` inside `winResize` function. But `drawer` was declared inside `$(document).ready` so `winResize` could not recognize what you meant by `drawer`.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    drawer = this.getElementById("drawer");
    topBar = this.getElementById("top-bar");
    drawerIsUp = false;

    function winResize() {
       drawer.style.top = topBar.offsetHeight + "px";
    }

    winResize();
    $(window).bind({resize: winResize, scroll: winScroll});
});
```

**Learn more about variable scopes**

https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

Comment: I have changed the code like you suggested but I still get an error. I have updated my question with the new code

Comment: It works now, function and a variable had the same name drawer, that was giving the error. But nothing happens on scroll event. Div is not sliding down.